# Number of independent generating sets of finite abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

How many independent (in the sense that if you throw an element out, it is not generating anymore) generating sets $S$ exist on a finite abelian group $G$? My first naive idea was that there shout be equally many for every possible cardinal $|S|$, namely $|Aut(G)|$ many, so $\#\{generating\, sets\, S\}=\#\{possible\,cardinals\,|S|\} \cdot |Aut(G)|$.. this seems not true.. is it?

Comment: Do you know the classification theorem for finite abelian groups?

Comment: Yes, both versions give a distinguished element $s \in S$..

Comment: You can actually count the number of possible generating sets up to relying on Euler's function, given that you need at least one from each cyclic factor... actually exactly one, since to generate a cyclic group you just need one element

Comment: But lets take $G=C_6$, then $\phi(6)=2$, but $C_6\cong C_2 \oplus C_3$ and thus there exist also minimal generating sets with 2 elements...

Comment: It is actually more complex than I thought, I will give it some thought. Anyway, do you mean minimal or minimum?

Comment: minimal in the sense that $G \cong \oplus_{i=1}^n C_{ord(g_i)}$ for $\{g_i \}_i =s \in S$

Comment: In your $C_6$ example, if $a$ is an element of order $6$, then both $\{a\}$ and $\{a^2, a^3\}$ are minimal generating sets. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes (and $\{ a^5\}$ of course)

Comment: You should really make it clear in the post what you mean by "minimal generating sets" , because there are two possible meanings, minimal by cardinality and minimal by inclusion. The second type are more usually called "independent" or "irredundant".

Comment: thx, changed it